# What is the prayer of faith as recorded in James 5:15?

Tags: prayer, book-of-james

[James 5:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%205%3A15&version=NRSV) says that the prayer of faith will save the sick. Is there a specific prayer of faith?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Though your question is a good one, it may not work here, since there could be a number of different answers depending on the perspective of the answerer. This site is primarily about the beliefs of various denominations, and the biblical basis of those beliefs. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Answer (score 2):

The verse is not referring to any specific prayer, but rather to the prayer of faith (ευχη της πιστεως) as opposed to prayer that is undertaken without faith.  For this reason James emphasizes a verse later:

> *The entreaty of a righteous man hath much strength*

He further provides Elijah as an example (v.17-18):

> *Elijah was a man subject to like passions as we are, and he prayed earnestly that it might not rain: and it rained not on the earth by
>   the space of three years and six months. And he prayed again, and the
>   heaven gave rain, and the earth brought forth her fruit.*

Comment: +1 that is the correct context. My answer was written in relation to the question before it was edited and the context in which it was asked which is the healing of the sick. It seemed to suggest that reciting a specific "Prayer of Faith" as the OP put it, would in turn heal a person. This is just not Biblically correct and, more importantly, taking the emphasis off God as the One who heals.

Answer (score -2):

The prayer of faith is not the "Prayer of Faith". This means, that there is not a specific prayer that a person can recite in order to heal someone else. God listens to His children. And He answers according to His will and to the measure of faith of the person asking. This is the prayer of faith that James is talking about.

A prayer is not something to be repeated without understanding, as Jesus said in His template of a prayer, now known as the Lord's Prayer; which oddly enough is repeated today throughout the world without understanding and just as vain repetition.

It can be found in Matthew 6:

> 7 And when you pray, **do not use vain repetitions as the heathen do.
>   For they think that they will be heard for their many words.**
>
> 8 “Therefore do not be like them. For your Father knows the things you
>   have need of before you ask Him. 9 In this manner, therefore, pray:
>
> Our Father in heaven, Hallowed be Your name. 10 Your kingdom come.
>   Your will be done On earth as it is in heaven. 11 Give us this day our
>   daily bread. 12 And forgive us our debts, As we forgive our debtors.
>   13 And do not lead us into temptation, But deliver us from the evil
>   one. For Yours is the kingdom and the power and the glory forever.
>   Amen.[c]

Prayer is meant to bring you in communion with God. It is meant to grow your faith and relationship with the Father and Christ. It is not to let God know something, as He already knows.

Steps to Christ p. 93

> Prayer is the opening of the heart to God as to a friend. Not that it
>   is necessary in order to make known to God what we are, but in order
>   to enable us to receive Him. Prayer does not bring God down to us, but
>   brings us up to Him.
>
> When Jesus was upon the earth, He taught His disciples how to pray. He
>   directed them to present their daily needs before God, and to cast all
>   their care upon Him. And the assurance He gave them that their
>   petitions should be heard, is assurance also to us.

For further information of prayer, I encourage you to read this small e-book:

https://www.amazingfacts.org/media-library/book/e/50/t/teach-us-to-pray

Comment: *which oddly enough is repeated today throughout the world without understanding and just as vain repetition*  Speak for yourself.   You have earned a -1 for making an unsupported assertion.  Which is too bad, since I find this to be perfect: *Prayer is meant to bring you in communion with God. It is meant to grow your faith and relationship with the Father and Christ. It is not to let God know something, as He already knows.*

Comment: We know who you're looking at, and that's not what this site is for, that is, hitting other Christian groups with clubs.

Comment: I downvoted the answer because I didn't feel it was the correct interpretation of James 5:15.  As a member of the Christian confession with perhaps the largest collection of service books, I don't necessarily disagree with the statement about "vain repetition".  It is a helpful reminder.  I would just say than "repetition" is not synonymous with "vain repetition".  Some people wrongly (in my opinion) equate formally recited prayers with "vain repetition".  If this were the case, then the entire Book of Psalms should be taken out of the Bible.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Hello friend. Are you saying you've never seen this done? My family and my wife's family have done this for generations. Movies and TV shows have repeated this, and it is not because it never happens, but because it is proliferated. The fact that it's done as penance I find even more problematic. It's almost like forgiveness by repetition.

Comment: @fredsbend hello Fred. I am not seeking to attack a religion here, or the people in it. I am simply pointing out something that is as it shouldn't be, regardless of religion. Is it more prolific in some religions? Yes, so I understand your concern, nevertheless, if I am in a position to show someone what the Word of God says of the subject, it is my duty to do so. Sin is also when a good man sees wrong and does nothing.

Comment: @user33515 I understand this sentiment. The book of Psalms is a songbook, but even songs should be sung with understanding. This is less about recited prayer, and more about reciting prayer without understanding. Recitation is very helpful and has its place, but without understanding it becomes vain repetition. That is what I'm saying.

Comment: **without understanding and just as vain repetition.**  You are generalizing, and making some assumptions about people who pray.  If you removed that half of your sentence, an unsupported, assertion, your point is still made quite well (about people doing that anyway) without pretending to assert a universal truth.  My experience is different from yours: some people *seem to do it by rote,* yes, and some take each phrase to heart when they pray the Our Father.  The experiential element of faith varies from person to person.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast One thing did come to mind. Baba Yetu, though a beautiful song and is the Lord's Prayer in Swahili, is a song that was composed for the Civilization IV game. Beautiful song, used for the wrong reason, and far from singing it with understanding, it was used for marketing of a game where God is nonexistent in civilization, or even worse, where you the player are god.

Comment: The amount of cultural appropriation done by TV and movies strikes me as beyond the scope of this question, though I (like you) find it in bad taste and borderline offensive.   If I had a nickel for the number of times someone says *madre de dios* or *Mother of God* in a movie in reaction to something happening ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I am not generalizing. I said "is repeated today without understanding". which is, unfortunately I would add, currently the truth. If I had said," Roman Catholics repeat it today without understanding" that would be a false statement and a gross generalization. There are many examples of this. I do appreciate your comments and hope the Lord blesses you in your walk with Him.

Comment: *currently the truth* ... as you see it.  I like the rest of your answer quite a bit, and I thank you for your warm engagement.  May your blessings increase each day ...